# Console dql join syntax?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, dql

I find it quite handy to write dql statements in console.
For example,

```
./symfony doctrine:dql "from sfGuardUser where id = 8"
```

But, however I try I just can't seem to write a join query properly. I would love it to work this:

```
./symfony doctrine:dql "from sfGuardUser s left join s.Profile"
```

But it doesn't. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it out, I could only get a normal join working (not a left join).

In this case a normal join is good enough. (One user has one profile)

```
./symfony doctrine:dql "from sfGuardUser s join s.Profile"
```

Comment: Thank you! In fact, it works like a left join (absent relations returned as Null).